# Initialize each element of the array with Student objects

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, object

```
public class Student { 
    int marks; 
    String name; 
    char sex; 
    String email; 
}
Student[] s = new Student[10];

public class StudentDemo {
    Student s[] = new Student[10];// array Student//
    Student s1  = new Student();//  Student Object//
    s1.setName("John"); //Eclipse says here there is a mistake an ask to delete John// 
    Student[0]=s1;
}
```

I have created a Student class with name and other attributes. But now I want to initialize each element of the array with Student objects. Is this code right? Eclipse throws a lot of red dots.
Help.

Comment: you need to write this code inside some method. You can't write logic directly inside a class.

Comment: Use s[0]=s1; instead of Student[0]=s1;.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 class Student { 
    int marks; 
    String name; 
    char sex; 
    String email;
    public void setName(String string)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 
}


public class StudentDemo{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    Student s[] = new Student[10];// array Student//
    Student s1  = new Student();//  Student Object//
    s1.setName("John"); //Eclipse says here there is a mistake an ask to delete John// 
    s[0]=s1;
    }
}
```

Try this. 
**Problems in your code:**

1. You wrote your function logic outside of function. Corrected in my
   code using main method.
2. You can't have 2 public classes in a class file. So i made Student file as non-public.
3. You din't have setter for name property of Student.

Answer (score 0):

Well you never defined a setName method so I am assuming thats why you got the compiler error. Something like this should work inside the Student class

```
 public String setName(String name){
          this.name = name;
    }
```

Comment: I defined all the setter and getters

Answer (score 0):

use the reference of the array you created instead of the type of array
Thus, replace `Student[0]` with `s[0]`

Answer (score 0):

A lot is wrong with your code.

It should be

```
 Student[] s = new Student[10];
 s[0] = new Student();
 s[0].setName();
```

You need to also write your code inside a method. Like so:

```
 public void doStuffHere()
 {
     // Code goes here.
 }
```

Notice I use that fact that at position `0` there is a `Student` object and then I just set the name. There is no real reason to use `s1`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

First of all, your first array should be written like this:

```
Student[] s = new Student[10];
```

Secondly, you never defined the method `setName(String name)` in your `Student` class. This would look something like this:

```
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

On top of that, you can't just call the method in the class, it needs to go inside a method, constructor, or initialisation block.

For example:

```
public class StudentDemo
{
    Student[] studentArray = initStudentArray();

    private Student[] initStudentArray()
    {
        Student[] ret = new Student[10];
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setName("John");
        ret[0] = s;

        ...

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you.

```
class Student { 
     int marks; 
     String name; 
     char sex; 
     String email; 

     void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;   //this.name represents the current instance non-static variable
     }
     public String toString(){   //Overridden Objectclass method for string representation of data
         return " Student Name: "+name+
            "\n Gender: "+sex+
            "\n Email: "+email+
            "\n Marks: "+marks;
     }
}

public class StudentDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args){
           Student s[] = new Student[10];
           s[0] = new Student();
           s[0].setName("John");  //similarly u can set values to other attributes of this object 
           System.out.println(s[0]);  // same as s[0].toString() its an implicit call
  }
}
```